# Alpakka and S3 truncating downloaded files

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, alpakka

I have a simple piece of code, based on alpakka examples, which should download some file from S3 for further processing:

```
S3.download(bucket, file)
  .runWith(Sink.head)
  .flatMap {
    case Some((data, _)) =>
      data.map(_.utf8String).runWith(Sink.head).map(Some.apply)
    case None =>
      Future.successful(None)
    }
```

The problem is that the file content is getting truncated, the file size from the `ObjectMetadata` is correct it has ~2M it isn't a huge file.

What I noticed is, when I use `Sink.head` the file content is from the beginning to middle if I change it to `Sink.last` it is from the middle to the end. Am I getting chunks from the file but why are they not seem to be streamed?

Can't figure out what's happening and how to fix this. I believe the issue is the same as this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451046/alpakka-s3-connector-does-not-provide-complete-file), unfortunately without answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, in the end it was very clear...

Just need to replace:
`data.map(_.utf8String).runWith(Sink.head).map(Some.apply)`

with:
`data.map(_.utf8String).runWith(Sink.seq).map(_.mkString).map(Some.apply)`

accumullating all the chunks from the file.

Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at [Benji S3](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/s3/usage.html) (I'm a contributor of)

Answer (score 0):

This approach took a lot of time in my case. Since i need to accumulate all the byteString and then put it in zip.
tested for file size 6 MB and it worked great.

Use

> data.reduce(_ + _).map(bytStr => {logic...})