# S3.getObject is truncating file contents in alpakka 4.0.0

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, alpakka, scala-2

I have a block of code like this:

```
  def downloadFilesSource(bucketName: String, primaryKey: String)(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext
  ): Source[(Source[ByteString, NotUsed], String), NotUsed] =
    S3.listBucket(bucketName, prefix = Some(primaryKey))
      .mapAsync(configuration.config.downloadParallelism.value)(
        (r: ListBucketResultContents) =>
          Future {
            S3.download(r.bucketName, r.key).zip(Source.single(r.key))
          }
      ) 
      .flatMapConcat(identity)
      .map {
        case (Some(x), key) => (x._1, key)
        case (None, _)      => throw new RuntimeException()
      }
```

which downloads all the files in an Amazon S3 bucket, and returns (a Source of) the contents tuple'd with the name of the file.

Upgrading to Alpakka 4.0.0, the `S3.download` method has been removed. The following code seemed like a good replacement:

```
def downloadFilesSource(bucketName: String, primaryKey: String)(
    implicit ec: ExecutionContext
  ): Source[(ByteString, String), NotUsed] = {
    S3.listBucket(bucketName, prefix = Some(primaryKey))
      .mapAsync(configuration.config.downloadParallelism.value)((r: ListBucketResultContents) =>
        Future {
          S3.getObject(r.bucketName, r.key).zip(Source.single(r.key))
        }
      ) 
      .flatMapConcat(identity)
}
```

However, the contents of the file is always truncated.

As an experiment, I also tried (in the function body):

```
    S3.listBucket(bucketName, prefix = Some(primaryKey))
      .map((r: ListBucketResultContents) => S3.getObject(r.bucketName, r.key).zip(Source.single(r.key)))
      .flatMapConcat(identity)
```

in case I wasn't waiting on the future correctly, but the files are truncated in the same way. I assume there's something I'm just missing about the streaming nature of Alpakka.

I've looked at [Alpakka and S3 truncating downloaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60744220/alpakka-and-s3-truncating-downloaded-files), but I don't see that the answers there are relevant :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problems I was having seems to be that, as the [Akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/zip.html) imply, a zip of sources will complete as soon as any one of the zipped streams completes. A `Source.single` is defined to complete after one object, so if `getObject` emits multiple chunks the zip will discard all subsequent chunks.

Handling the get like this, and mapping the complete bytestring to a tuple afterwards (in place of the zip) avoids the truncation:

```
        S3.getObject(r.bucketName, r.key)
          .fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)
          .map(byteString => (byteString, r.key))
```